# In bash shell, how can I filter an array of paths based on whether an element exists?

Tags: bash, files, array

I'm using bash shell.  I have this array representing file paths

```
MY_FILES=(/path/to/file1 /tmp/abc.txt /tmp/test.sh /path/to/file2 /path/to/file3 /tmp/abc.txt)
```

How can I form a new array of elements in which the paths actually exist on my file system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```bash
MY_FILES=(/path/to/file1 /tmp/abc.txt /tmp/test.sh /path/to/file2 /path/to/file3 /tmp/abc.txt)

existing=()
for pathname in "${MY_FILES[@]}"; do
    if [ -e "$pathname" ]; then
        existing+=( "$pathname" )
    fi
done
```

The above creates a new array, `existing`, which contains the entries from the `MY_FILES` array corresponding to existing names in the filesystem. It does this by iterating over the entries in your array, testing each element in turn with the `-e` test, which is *true* if the given pathname exists. If the current pathname exists, it is appended as a new element at the end of the `existing` array.

If you also want to ensure that each name is a *regular file*, change the `-e` test into an `-f` test.